# Jquery, getting the column data of selected row using jtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtable

I have 3 fields in my jtable; Name, Age, Occupation.Lets say I select a specific row, How would i get the specific column data of that row?

Ex:

I select the following row: 
Row 2: Joe Brown, 25, Teacher

How would I get the age data (which is 25) of that row ?

Thanks

PS: I intend to delete that row, so I need the name to query the sql database properly (im using jdbc)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourTable tr').each(function() {
    var age = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();    
    alert(age);// for testing purpose
});
```

You will get the value of the second row (the index is zero-based)

Answer (score 1):

```
var rowIndex = // the zero based index of the selected row
var age = $('.jtable tbody').children(rowIndex).children('td').eq(1).text(); // return the age
```